# Sqlite query returns different results from different classes

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a repository class that returns data from an sqlite database. Here is a basic example:

```
class FeedbackRepository:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('feedback.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.setupDatabase()

    def setupDatabase(self):
        sql = """
                  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FeedbackEntries
                  (
                      id TEXT NOT NULL,
                      rep TEXT,
                      rating TEXT NOT NULL
                  )
              """
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.connection.commit()

    def getAllFeedback(self):
        sql = """SELECT * FROM FeedbackEntries"""
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return [self._getFeedbackEntryModelFromRow(row) for row in data]
```

I am creating an instance of this class in two different `.py` files, and each time I call `getAllFeedback()`. In one file, all of the feedback is returned from the database query. The second file, returns an empty collection from the `cursor.fetchall()`. The code from the two files does not run concurrently, I run the scripts at separate time, and so there should never be more than one connection at any time (if that even makes a difference).

I have no idea how this could happen, especially as both scripts are using the same code ?

Comment: You are using a relative path in the `connect()` call; is your working directory the same in both cases?

Comment: No, they are in different directories. And I hate myself. I'm off to hide in a corner somewhere. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path in the `sqlite3.connect()` call; this means the exact location of the database file depends on the current working directory. If you execute the script from a different location, the database file will be re-created.

Use an absolute path instead; you can base it of the location of the module with:

```
import os

_module_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

then:

```
self.connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(_module_directory, 'feedback.db'))
```